# Why do I encounter "INVALID_PARAMETER VALUE" error when opening "Models" tab in MLFlow UI?

Tags: mlflow

I installed mlflow via pip and opened it in the browser through the terminal. The tab Experiments displays normally; however, when I switch to Models tab, the app crashes due to the following error:

```
INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Model registry functionality is unavailable; 
got unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry data storage. 
Supported URI schemes are: ['postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']. 
See https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#storage for how to run 
an MLflow server against one of the supported backend storage locations.
```

I would like to log model data locally without connecting to external servers or databases. I thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

According to MLflow [documentations](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#model-registry-workflows)

> If running your own MLflow server, you must use a database-backed backend store in order to access the model registry via the UI or API.

So you should use `--backend-store-uri` to configure the database-backed store. MLflow supports the database dialects **MySQL**, **MS SQL**, **SQLite**, and **PostgreSQL**. You can read more [here](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#backend-stores).

For example, `--backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db` would use a local SQLite database.

```
mlflow ui --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db
```